# wpf bind different datatemplates to different types of objects in contentcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF and MVVM. What I am trying to do is to bind two different DataTemplates to two different kinds of objects in one ContentControl. Each kind of object corresponds to one DataTemplate.

The two kinds of objects are called Unit and Component respectively. They contain different properties. For example a Unit has 3 properties: *Id*, *Name* and *Manufacture*. A Component has 3 properties *Id*, *Type* and *Materials*. The example code is as below:

```
public class Unit : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _id;
    private string _name;
    private string _manufacture;

    public int Id
    {
        get {return this._id}
        set
        {
            this._id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Id")
        }
    {
    public string Name
    {
        get {return this._name}
        set
        {
            this._id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name")
        }
    {
    public string Manufacture
    {
        get {return this._manufacture}
        set
        {
            this._id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Manufacture")
        }
    {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    ...
}
```

The Component class has the similar structure.

In the MainWindow, I have a ListBox listing names of objects (I will change it to a TreeView in the future) on the left, and a ContentControl on the right. I want that when I select the name of an object, the details of the object will be shown on the right. The code of the MainWindow is as below:

```
<Windows.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource
        Source="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=UnitItems}"
        x:Key="UnitDataView">
    </CollectionViewSource>

    <CollectionViewSource
        Source="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=ComponentItems}"
        x:Key="ComponentDataView">
    </CollectionViewSource>

    <CompositeCollection x:Key="AllDataView
        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource UnitDataView}}" />
        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ComponentDataView}}" />
    </CompositeCollection>

<local: PartDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MyDataTemplateSelector"
                                 UnitTemplate="{StaticResource unitTemplate}"
                                 ComponentTemplate="{StaticResource componentTemplate}" />
</Windows.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinition>

    <ListBox x:Name="ComponentListView" Grid.Column="0"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AllDataView}}" />

    <TabControl Grid.Column="1"
        <TabItem Header="Basic Info">
            <ContentControl x:Name="BasicInfoContent"
                            ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}"
                            Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource AllDataView}}">
            </ContentControl>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

The `UnitItems` and `ComponentItems` are two `ObservableCollection<T>` objects defined in App.xaml.cs. And I have defined some DataTemplates in App.xaml. The example code is as below:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="..."
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Unit}">
        <!-- This template is to show the name of a unit object in the ListBox -->
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Component}">
        <!-- This template is to show the name of a component object in the ListBox -->
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="unitTemplate" DataType="{x:Type src:Unit}">
        <!-- This template is to show the details of a unit object in the ContentControl -->
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="componentTemplate" DataType="{x:Type src:Component}">
        <!-- This template is to show the details of a component object in the ContentControl -->
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

And my custom DataTemplateSelector is as below:

```
class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate UnitTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate ComponentTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        swith (item)
        {
            case Unit _:
                return UnitTemplate;
            case Component _:
                return ComponentTemplate;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have read this article [ContentTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Controls_ContentControl_ContentTemplateSelector) and tried the ContentTemplateSelector, but since I use a CompositeCollection and CollectionContainer to bind these two kinds of objects in the ContentControl, the item object in my DataTemplateSelector class receives the CompositeCollection type, not a Unit type nor a Component type, so there is no proper template being returned. Also I tried the method mentioned in this article [DataType Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype?view=netframework-4.7.2), which is to set a DataType property for each of the DataTemplate and set the Path to "/". Maybe I misunderstood it, but it did not work either, where I think it has the same issue with the ContentTemplateSelector one. So anybody can help me on this problem?

It is my very first time to ask a question on Stack Overflow. I know some of my description and codes are trivial to this question, but I just don't want to miss any details that may be related to my problem. I apologise for that. Also if there are any problem with my coding style and data structure, please feel free to point it out. I really appreciate it. Thank you for your reading and help!

Comment: Hi Kenny, is your data (all units and components) correct shown in your list on the left side?

Comment: Yes, they are. Actually I created a Border in their ListBox's DataTemplates, and a TextBlock in the Border binding to the name for Unit and the type for Component. So in the ListBox a Unit object is shown in its name and a Component object is shown in its type.

Comment: Ok, have a look at Clemens answer. I wanted suggest the same solution but he was faster ;)

Comment: It does solve my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need a DataTemplateSelector. Just make sure that the detail DataTemplates can be automatically selected, by not assining a key to them.

It also seems that you don't need two collections for your objects. You might as well derive both Unit and Component from a common base class and have a single collection of base class references.

Finally there should be a view model, which besides the objects collection also has a property for the currently selected object.

Take this simplified example view model:

```
public class Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Unit : Base
{
    public string UnitData { get; set; }
}

public class Component : Base
{
    public string ComponentData { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Base> Objects { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Base>();

    private Base selectedObject;

    public Base SelectedObject
    {
        get { return selectedObject; }
        set
        {
            selectedObject = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
               new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedObject)));
        }
    }
}
```

An instance of it should be assigned to the window's DataContext:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new ViewModel();
    vm.Objects.Add(new Unit { Id = 1, UnitData = "Unit Data" });
    vm.Objects.Add(new Component { Id = 2, ComponentData = "Component Data" });

    DataContext = vm;
}
```

Finally, the XAML would be this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Unit}">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="Unit, Id:"/>
                <Run  Text="{Binding Id}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Component}">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="Component, Id:"/>
                <Run  Text="{Binding Id}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
<ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding SelectedObject}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Unit}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding UnitData}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Component}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ComponentData}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Hi Clemens, thank you so much. One more question, do I have to derive these two classes from a base class to implement your strategy? Because the true relation between Unit and Component is that a Unit can contain many Components. You can treat a Unit like an equipment and Component like different parts of the equipment. So they actually have no properties in common. If I insist my original data structure, it seems I cannot bind the SelectedObject in your way. Am I right?

Comment: You do not really need the common base class. Just use `public ObservableCollection<Base> Objects` and `public object SelectedObject`

Comment: I tried `public ObservableCollection<Object> Objects` and I guess that is what you mean. It works pretty well. Thank you!

Comment: Of course, `public ObservableCollection<object> Objects`